# App icon doesn't appear after implementing deep links to my app

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm developing an app in Android Studio it works pretty well, but after implementing deep links to my launching activity my app doesn't you the app icon in the menu, I know the app is installed cause in Setting>Applications it appears. I know the problem is in the manifest.xml, so I'll leave a copy down bellow.

I'll love to hear about your solutions, by the way if you are reading this thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dev.misterj.nocherd">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permision.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAiJNpq-********************" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".StartActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "https://myapp.com/place” -->
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="myapp.com"  android:pathPrefix="/place"  />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "myapp://place” -->
                <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="place" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>


</manifest>
```

Comment: I think your manifest is not well-formed. have you tried to uninstall the previous app and install the new one?  does it allows you to install?

Comment: You forgot to close <application> section. Add </application> above </manifest>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should separate the intent filters, also your manifest file is not well-formatted. you should close the application tag. you can open it with an external application like google chrome, it will tell you if the XML is not in correct format.

```
<activity android:name=".StartActivity">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="place"/>

    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="myapp.com" android:pathPrefix="/place" />
      </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

it's important that you create separate filters when your intention is to declare unique URLs (such as a specific combination of scheme and host) because multiple `<data>` elements in the same intent filter are actually merged together to account for all variations of their combined attributes. if you combine them it actually supports `https://place` and also supports `myapp://myapp.com/place`.
So you should separate them.

Comment: That was fast. Thanks a lot S.A.Parkhid !